# upload files using XTRF REST API

Tags: xtrf

I have tried a form submit with files example all the files are getting uploaded to XTRF and getting the response.

Now I am using blueimp jquery file uploader[http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/]. If I upload image files it is getting uploaded to XTRF. If I upload any other files it is not getting uploaded to XTRF. I am getting workfile.rtf as response with junk data.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Need to upload files to XTRF using ajax uploader.

Answer (score 0):

POST /system/session/files

Accepts files encoded as multipart/form-data and stores them temporarily (they are available only within current session). Each file gets its own id and basic statistics: number of characters (with and without spaces), words, lines, pages.
sample html form for file upload

```
  <form id="upload" action="baseURL/system/session/files" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label>Select a file:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" size="45"></input>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
```

You can also send plain text assigned to parameter content encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Such text will be stored as uploaded file.
sample html form that sends text for upload

```
  <form id="sourceText" action="baseUrl/system/session/files" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
   <label>Source text:</label>
   <textarea name="content" rows="5" columns="40"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
 </form>
```

Uploaded files can be attached to quote request or while updating user's profile.